# How to get a Virtual Machine Network information via SNMP from ESXi

Tags: networking, monitoring, virtual, snmp, esxi

I want to monitor the inbound/outbound traffic of a VM inside ESXi through SNMP. I activated SNMP protocol on ESXi and can get information with snmpwalk and snmpget. But I don't know which OID is the wright one to get the network info of my desired VM. 
I want to get some information like the ones that the following commands return inside ESXi shell: 
esxcli network vm list
esxcli network vm port list -w 
esxcli network port stats get -p

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you've configured SNMP Agent properly: [Configure SNMP for ESXi](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc_50%2FGUID-8EF36D7D-59B6-4C74-B1AA-4A9D18AB6250.html)
2. ESXi supports all standard MIBs like `IF-MIB`, `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB`, `BRIDGE-MIB` and others.
3. Also it does support some vendor specific MIBs: `VMWARE-RESOURCES-MIB`, `VMWARE-ENV-MIB` and some others

Comment: Thank you Andrew, it was helpful. I have configure SNMP agent and can get a lot of data, but I cannot find any specific OID or MIB for which reveals information such as the ones I can get from esxi shell. Like the command 'esxcli network vm list' which gives me the name of the virtual machine and their corresponding World IDs or more important one 'esxcli network port stats get -p <portID>' which displays the traffic usage of a VM which is really important for me.

Comment: Did you check IF-MIB? It does have a table that contains network stats for each interface.

Comment: Yep. I did a snmpwalk and stored the whole output in a file and then check all IF-MIB entries one by one. But none of them showed the traffic of my VM or even it's IP address or MAC address!!!